# What is the highest amount of Lollipops per Second I can get?

Tags: candy-box-2

On "The Candy Box 2," what is the highest amount of Lollipops per Second I can get? How do I get it to that point?

Comment: Theoretically infinite.  Just keep buying loligators.

Comment: Technically, (end-game spoiler) could make it whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100 lps is the highest amount the regular farm can produce. Otherwise, the number can be infinite, depending on how many lolligators you have, but for the cost of candy.